# Java Scramble Game Input after Hint

Tags: java, input

I'm modifying an unscramble game in Java. I have two arrays: one for the original words and another for their hints. So when the user guesses incorrectly, the corresponding hint shows up and what I want is for the user to have another chance to guess after the hint is shown. But right now, I can't seem to get that 'another chance' to work. Can someone pls help? Thank you.

Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

// How to create a Jumble word game in Java
 
public class MyProgram {
 
    private static final String[] WORDS_DATABASE = new String[] {
        "code","kids","baby", "dosa", "beach","house","apple", "paper", 
        "Java", "school", "science", "Oracle", "Disney", "cricket", "carrot",
        "vada"
    };
    
    private static String[] hints = new String[] {
        "Programs are made of ___", "Synonym for children", "Synonym for infant",
        "Idli, vada, and ___", "This place is next to ocean", "Other word for 'home'", 
        "This is a red color fruit", "pencil and ____", "programming language", 
        "place for education", "Physics, chemistry, biology are all ____", 
        "Larry Ellison founded this company", "the ____ princesses", "Famous sport with bat and ball",
        "What rabbits eat", "idli and ___"
    };
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyProgram jg = new MyProgram();
        jg.startGame();

        
    }
 
    /**
     * Run a game of Jumble in Java. The steps in the game are,
     * 1. Get a random word from the words database
     * 2. Shuffle/jumble the word by randomly shuffling characters
     * 3. Present the jumbled word to the user and ask him to guess the word.
     * 4. Repeat the guess till answer is found or user decides to quit.
     */
    private void startGame() {
       // int numberOfGuesses = 0;
       // String original = selectRandomWord();
        
        
        //String shuffled = getShuffledWord(original);
        boolean gameOn = true;
        while(gameOn) {
            int numberOfGuesses = 0;
            String original = selectRandomWord();
        
        
            String shuffled = getShuffledWord(original);

            System.out.println("Shuffled word is: "+shuffled);
            
            numberOfGuesses++;
            String userGuess = getUserGuess();
            if(original.equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess)) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You found the word in "+numberOfGuesses+" guesses");
                System.out.println("");
                //gameOn = false;
            }else {
                
                System.out.println("Sorry, Wrong answer");
                System.out.println("--------");
                if (numberOfGuesses > 0){
                    displayHint(original);
                    System.out.println("");
                  //  String userGuess = getUserGuess();
                }
            }
        }        
    }
     
    /**
     * Get the user's word guess from command line
     * @return 
     */
    public String getUserGuess() {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type in the original word: ");
        return sn.nextLine();
    }
     
    /**
     * Select a random word from the WORDS_DATABASE array.
     * @return 
     */
    public String selectRandomWord() {
        int rPos = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, WORDS_DATABASE.length);
        return WORDS_DATABASE[rPos];
    }
     
    /**
     * Shuffle the original word by randomly swapping characters 10 times
     * @param original
     * @return 
     */
    public String getShuffledWord(String original) {
        String shuffledWord = original; // start with original
        int wordSize = original.length();
        int shuffleCount = 10; // let us randomly shuffle letters 10 times
        for(int i=0;i<shuffleCount;i++) {
            //swap letters in two indexes
            int position1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, wordSize);
            int position2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, wordSize);
            shuffledWord = swapCharacters(shuffledWord,position1,position2);
        }
        return shuffledWord;
    }
 
    /**
     * Swaps characters in a string using the given character positions
     * @param shuffledWord
     * @param position1
     * @param position2
     * @return 
     */
    private String swapCharacters(String shuffledWord, int position1, int position2) {
        char[] charArray = shuffledWord.toCharArray();
        // Replace with a "swap" function, if desired:
        char temp = charArray[position1];
        charArray[position1] = charArray[position2];
        charArray[position2] = temp;
        return new String(charArray);
    }
    
    private void displayHint(String s){
        for (int i = 0; i < WORDS_DATABASE.length; i++){
            if (WORDS_DATABASE[i].equals(s)){
                System.out.println("HINT:" + hints[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So when the user guesses incorrectly, the corresponding hint shows up
> and what I want is for the user to have another chance to guess after
> the hint is shown. But right now, I can't seem to get that 'another
> chance' to work.

You just need to move the selection and scrambling of the word to BEFORE the `while` loop so that it doesn't pick a new word when they guess wrong.  Also, why did you comment out the `gameOn = false;` line?  That is necessary to allow the game to end.

After you move the initialization lines to before the `while` loop, you can now place that entire thing inside another `while` loop that asks the user if they want to play a new game (I'll leave that to you, though).

```
int numberOfGuesses = 0;
String original = selectRandomWord();
String shuffled = getShuffledWord(original);

while(gameOn) {
    System.out.println("Shuffled word is: "+shuffled);
    
    numberOfGuesses++;
    String userGuess = getUserGuess();
    if(original.equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess)) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You found the word in "+numberOfGuesses+" guesses");
        System.out.println("");
        gameOn = false;
    }else {
        
        System.out.println("Sorry, Wrong answer");
        System.out.println("--------");
        if (numberOfGuesses > 0){
            displayHint(original);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the user guesses incorrectly, it will display the hint and go back to the top of the `while` loop where it will ask the user for another guess.  It will stay in the loop until they get it correct and `gameOn` is toggled to false.

> But how do I make it so that the user gets to input whether they want
> to play on or not, after the round ends?

You could change your `main()` to something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (keepPlaying) {
      MyProgram jg = new MyProgram();
      jg.startGame();

      
      System.out.print("Would you like to play again? [Y or YES]: ");
      String response = sn.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      keepPlaying = (response.equals("Y") || (response.equals("YES")));
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Hello all, thanks for helping! It worked now. But how do I make it so that the user gets to input whether they want to play on or not, after the round ends? (I'm relatively new to Java game dev. so I'm still learning the logic and stuff) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop at startGame() for playing again with new word like:

```java
boolean playAgain = true;
while(playAgain)
    playAgain = jg.startGame();
```

Modify the startGame() to return true when the user wants to play again otherwise false. Also, move the random word selection and word shuffling statements outside of the gameOn loop to stop getting new word even when the user gives the right answer.

```java
private boolean startGame() {
    boolean gameOn = true;
    int numberOfGuesses = 0;
    String original = selectRandomWord();
    String shuffled = getShuffledWord(original);
    System.out.println("Shuffled word is: "+shuffled);
    while(gameOn) {
        numberOfGuesses++;
        String userGuess = getUserGuess();
        if(original.equalsIgnoreCase(userGuess)) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You found the word in "+numberOfGuesses+" guesses");
            System.out.println("");
            gameOn = false;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, Wrong answer");
            System.out.println("--------");
            if (numberOfGuesses > 0){
                displayHint(original);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
    if(checkIfUserwantsToPlayAgain())
        return true; // To restart the game
    return false; // To stop the game
}
```